# Next JS 13 Api route with body request, always timeout in production [firebase backend]

Tags: firebase, next.js, fetch-api, next.js13

I am building a Next 13  app with a firebase backend. I am using the latest AppRouter version of Next ("13.4.12"). I have multiple api routes which interact with Firestore databases for getting, adding and updating data. All my api endpoints work well in development env but after I deploy the app into production it seems like all the requests which have a body payload (POST, PUT..) are getting a timeout error. The GET requests they all work fine in production. I am using the fetch api from next but i did try it with axios too and got the same timeout status.

Somehow it seems like sending a stringified JSON object into the body (which i have always done in previous versions of next) breaks the request. I also tried sending a plain string as a body request and then it seems to work.

I will share my current implementation, maybe someone finds what am i doing wrong or if there is a bug in Next 13.

**1. Api Route**

```
export async function POST(
  request: NextRequest,
  context: { params: { id: string } }
) {
  try {


    const body = await request.json(); 
    console.log("body--------", body);


    // Get the id from the url query
    const id = context.params.id;

    // Reference to the Firestore collection

    const pageDocRef = firestoreAdmin.collection("Pages").doc(id);


    await pageDocRef.update(body);

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "PUT request" }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log("error", error);
    if (error instanceof FirebaseError) {
      if (
        error.code === "auth/insufficient-permission" ||
        error.code === "permission-denied"
      )
        return NextResponse.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
    }
    return NextResponse.json({ error }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

**2. The request from a client component/page**

```
  const handleUpdatePageData = async (data: Partial<IPage>) => {
    await fetch("/api/pages/home", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then(() => {
        // router.refresh();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

**3. CORS middleware setup**

```
  ///////  Set the CORS headers
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  // ///// Set the CORS headers
  const response = NextResponse.next();

  response.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.headers.set(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
  );

  response.headers.set(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Authorization"
  );
  response.headers.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");

  /////// [end OF] -> Set the CORS headers



  console.log("\x1b[35m", "EXECUTING MIDDLEWARE-------->");




  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next.js inherently manages CORS for its API routes, so there's typically no need for additional CORS middleware, especially when interactions are within the same origin. If you're communicating cross-origin, it's crucial to specify your production domain in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header rather than resorting to a wildcard "*", which can lead to complications, especially when credentials are involved.

Turning our attention to the primary concern, it's worth noting that function timeouts might be at the root of the challenges you're facing. Time-intensive operations, especially those involving external network requests like interactions with Firestore, can easily cause these timeouts. Remember, Next.js's API operates in a stateless manner, akin to cloud functions. This structure doesn't support certain persistent connections, such as websockets.

Comment: Hi, Hidayet! Thanks for your response. 

The problem was that the body of the request was processed once by firebase cloud functions (eg. https.onRequest) and then again by the next js internal api route. From what i have seen this happens only with next 13 app dir. It never happend to me with the old Pages Dir version of Next. Hope this helps someone out there. Cheers!